# Sublime Python Build Not Working [WinError 5] Access is denied

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I am trying to build python 3.8.5 onto my sublime so I can compile python files. I have used the following code to insert the build

```
 "cmd":["C:/Users/*******/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32", "-u", "$file"],
 "file_regex": "^[ ]File \"(...?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
 "selector": "source.python"
```

However, whenever i try to run a python file, this error occurs `[WinError 5] Access is denied`
I do not know why this is occurring. I have installed python 3.8.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting an `Access Denied` error because the first item in `cmd` is the executable that should be executed by the build system, but in place of an executable you've instead specified the name of a directory instead. You can't execute a directory, so `Access is denied`.

The actual Python interpreter is inside of the folder that you've specified here, so adding `python.exe` to the end of the path you've placed there should solve your problem.

Comment: Hi OdatNurd I added the /python.exe at the end of the file directory however, it will not execute the code when compiled

Comment: Your install may differ from mine; check inside of that folder to see what it's named.

Comment: When I select properties on python the file directory is C:\Users\*******\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32 but when I insert this into the sublime build i dont have permission because the same error is produced

Comment: Again, that's because that is a directory and not an executable; the executable lives inside of that folder and has an `.exe` extension on it.

Comment: I put the python.exe onto the directory however I receive an output for he checkversion.py file however, i have no output when I am running another .py file